# Php runkit_import and final classes

Tags: php, phpunit, runkit

I read here: http://osdir.com/ml/php.phpunit.user/2008-05/msg00009.html that changing a class `final` behaviour may be changed with runkit - I just cant see the way how.

EDIT: dont -1 me pls, I checked the runkit_import() function and also the http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.constants.php still cant find the way

Answer (score 1):

It's of... limited use. An illustration:

```
final class Foo {
    protected $var = '456';
    function doSomething(){
        return '123';
    }
    function getVar(){
        return $this->var;
    }
}

class Bar {

}
runkit_class_adopt('Bar','Foo');

$d = new Bar();
var_dumP($d->doSomething());
//string(3) "123"
var_dumP($d->getVar());
//PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Bar::$var in .... on line 10
//NULL
```

You're usually better of writing a Decorator for `final` classes (or removing the `final` from the source).

Comment: of course, but with this analogy, we could simply say "change all private/protected to public"

Comment: Final classes are meant to be final, if you _need_ them to be non-final fixing the problem at its source is indeed more apt. In that respect it does reflect the private/protected/public scenario: one usually makes as much private or protected as possible, but if there's an abolute need of exposing something as public one does. BTW: that wouldn't help in this `runkit_class_adopt` illustration either: public properties fail just as hard.